# What are examples of fiction books picked up by publishers after being self-published?

Tags: fiction, self-publishing

I've seen some references to commercial publishers picking up a self-published novel if it's been selling well.

Can you point me to a few specific examples of this happening?

Fiction only, please. I'm particularly interested in cases where the author had no popular platform independent of his writing (e.g. not Cory Doctrow, or *Machine of Death* which was published by several popular webcomic artists). Anything within science-fiction or fantasy would be of particular interest to me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Michael Wallace](http://www.amazon.com/Michael-Wallace/e/B004KAMJX2) has just signed a five book publishing deal with Thomas & Mercer, the new publishing imprint from Amazon. He writes mystery/suspense and has been solely self-published until now.

[Michael Sullivan](http://riyria.blogspot.com/) has signed a five book deal with Orbit Books. He writes fantasy novels and has been solely self-published until now.

[J. Carson Black](http://jcarsonblack.com/) just signed a book publishing deal with Thomas & Mercer. I don't recall how many books were in the deal, but I believe it was three. I believe she had been previously published but got dropped and then went into self-publishing. Now she's back in traditional publishing.

Of course, everyone has no doubt heard about Amanda Hocking's multi-million dollar deal to publish three new contemporary or urban fantasy novels. In addition, a couple of publishers tried to convince John Locke to sign with them, but he declined. Having sold over a million e-books on his own, I guess he didn't really feel the need to change anything.

There are several others that have done this recently, but these were the ones that immediately came to mind. I may add a couple more later.

Update: [Scott Nicholson](http://hauntedcomputer.blogspot.com/2011/08/nicholson-signs-book-deal-with-amazon.html), another indie author, has just signed a two book deal with Thomas & Mercer. Scott writes primarily thrillers, and he does have a background in traditional publishing. However, he went indie and found success with a couple of his self-published books, and now he is back with a publisher.

[Louise Voss](http://www.thisislondon.co.uk/standard/article-23975171-writer-puts-novel-on-kindle-for-96p-and-wins-a-six-figure-deal.do) shot to the top of the Kindle charts by self-publishing her book after being rejected by literary agents. It attracted the attention of publishers HarperFiction, which offered her a six-figure, four-book deal. As a result, her ebook Catch Your Death will also be printed and stocked in bookshops by a traditional publisher.

[Jessica Meigs](http://becomingzombies.com/) self-published two zombie novellas and was picked up by Permuted Press for a three book deal.

**Last edit, I promise!** 
JA Konrath has been an openly outspoken proponent of self-publishing for some time. I knew that he had compiled a list at one time of self-published authors with no previous experience or exposure to traditional publishing. I'll let [his list](http://jakonrath.blogspot.com/2011/01/response-to-richard-curtis.html) serve as a much better compilation of success stories.

Answer (score 4):

[Amanda Hocking's](http://amandahocking.blogspot.com/2011/05/and-yet-another-announcement.html) the big name on this one, I'd say.  YA supernatural, as I understand it, but I haven't read her work myself.

There's also *[Eragon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eragon)*, although I recall hearing some debate about just how 'self' published the book was.  (I can't remember the details of the debate... anybody?)

Comment: I was going to mention her too, but I wasn't sure if she qualified, because the question asked for an example of a self-published novel that was picked up. Amanda Hocking was picked up to write a new series, wasn't she, not to have her other books republished?

Comment: I guess as far as I'm concerned, the distinction I'm intrigued by would be whether she was "picked up" solely on the strength of her self-published work, vs. selling a novel "the usual way" after having self-published previously. If they took her for a new, unwritten series, that sounds on strength of the self-pubbed work, which is basically what I'm aiming for.

Comment: If you click the link I gave for Amanda Hocking, it certainly sounds like the self published books are going to be reissued by the new publisher.

Comment: **Re: _Eragon_** - From what I've found, author's parents ran a very very small commercial press, and the book was published both through that and an online POD service. So... practically self-publishing for all most purposes, but under the auspices of a regular publisher, and with parents who had an extraordinary amount of industry know-how and put in an extraordinary level of effort. And, fittingly, reached an extraordinary level of success :)

Comment: cf.: [here](http://absolutewrite.com/forums/showpost.php?p=3458946&postcount=29) and [here](http://jimhines.livejournal.com/313073.html); Wikipedia also mentions the POD service, which was apparently in addition to the family publishing.

Answer (score 2):

Contest by Matthew Reilly:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contest_(novel)

Once, long ago, I read that Dan Brown's Digital Fortress was originally self-published... but if this is true it has since been excised from the record...

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you are meaning by being self-published I believe that [Scott Sigler](http://www.amazon.com/Scott-Sigler/e/B001IGOKQA/), [Mur Lafferty](http://www.amazon.com/Mur-Lafferty/e/B002I0MP44/) and [Nathan Lowell](http://www.amazon.com/Nathan-Lowell/e/B003D54RY4/) are examples as well.

Comment: Oooh - podcasting to publishing. Cool. :)